# Wordpress permantlink error404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I am doing a wordpress page on digitalocean. I have a problem when I set permantlinks in my dashboard. The problem is, the server switch links, but sending to a 404 page.

`http://5.101.99.123/` there is my server.

1. I Delete old .htaccess
2. Module rewrite already enable (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
3. I tried 777 on .htaccess
4. The server is working on ubuntu 14.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to settings->permalinks and select default, and check its working or not.

Comment: You may just need to flush the permalink cache.  Go to the admin screen @Hareesh mentioned and save the permalinks (without changing anything else)

Comment: @hareesh If I select default It's working okey. But only default...  

hobo I tried it, but didnt work

Comment: Hope this will help [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-does-not-work-apart-from-default#post-768025)

Comment: @Hareesh I tried it, but now all links are holding main page. I tried <directory /var/www>
 AllowOverride All
<directory>
and
<Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   AllowOverride FileInfo
  </Directory>

Comment: @Hareesh I fixed it!! It was a plugin "All In One WP Security" I disabled and everything is okey now. Btw Thanks very much for your help buddy ;)